# Display Column if Count of Boolean Parameters is Greater than an Amount in SQL Server Report Viewer

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I want to display a column in a MSSQL Report, if more than 2 out of 4 boolean report parameters are true.  Below is the attempt I made to create a visibility expression for this condition but it causes an error. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
=IIF(COUNT(IIF(Parameters!HideQuantityOnHand.Value = "False" OR Parameters!HideQuantityOnOrder.Value = "False" OR Parameters!HideCostPerItem.Value = "False" OR Parameters!HideRetailPerItem.Value = "False")) < 3, true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't `Count` because of the `OR` in the statement. It just doesn't look right.  So all you need is 1 to be `false`, assuming that the others are `true`. See if this works for you.

**UPDATED** See if this is what you wanted. I think I got all of the combinations.

```
            =IIF((Parameters!HideQuantityOnHand.Value = "False" AND Parameters!HideQuantityOnOrder.Value = "False") OR 
            (Parameters!HideQuantityOnHand.Value = "False" AND Parameters!HideCostPerItem.Value = "False") OR 
         (Parameters!HideQuantityOnHand.Value = "False" AND Parameters!HideRetailPerItem.Value = "False")
        OR (Parameters!HideQuantityOnOrder.Value = "False" AND Parameters!HideCostPerItem.Value = "False") OR
     (Parameters!HideQuantityOnOrder.Value AND Parameters!HideRetailPerItem.Value = "False") OR
(Parameters!HideCostPerItem.Value = "False" AND Parameters!HideRetailPerItem.Value = "False") , true, false)
```

Comment: I believe your expression will evaluate properly if any 1 of the parameters are "False", but I wanted the visibility to be set to "true" if 2 or more of any combination of the columns are "False".

Comment: Ok. 2 or more is different from `if more than 2 out of 4 boolean report parameters are true`.  So you'll have to group each set of 2 with an `AND`, with the other group separated by `OR`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to provide a detailed answer, however your expression did not provide the result I needed in my report.  The expression that worked for me is listed above.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after.

```
=(
    IIF(Parameters!HideQuantityOnHand.Value ,1,0) + 
    IIF(Parameters!HideQuantityOnOrder.Value ,1,0) + 
    IIF(Parameters!HideCostPerItem.Value ,1,0) + 
    IIF(Parameters!HideRetailPerItem.Value ,1,0) 
    ) < 3
```

Basically we evaluate each parameter and convert true to 1, we then sum all the values and check they are < 3 in which case we return True to the hidden property (so it's not visible).

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the example below I found that I had to join three parameters with AND and then specify true or false for the visibility in the expression followed by IIF for the expression comparison.  See below.

```
=IIf(Parameters!HideQuantityOnHand.Value="False" AND
Parameters!HideQuantityOnOrder.Value="False" AND
Parameters!HideRetailPerItem.Value="False" AND
Parameters!HideCostPerItem.Value="False",true,
IIf(Parameters!HideQuantityOnOrder.Value="False" AND
Parameters!HideCostPerItem.Value="False",true,
IIf(Parameters!HideCostPerItem.Value="False" AND
Parameters!HideQuantityOnHand.Value="False",true,
IIf(Parameters!HideRetailPerItem.Value="False" 
AND Parameters!HideQuantityOnHand.Value="False",true,false))))
```